# Не могу понять принцип работы параметров маршрутизатора

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Не могу понять принцип работы аргумента id на MVC, так как, когда создаю action

```
public class MovieController : Controller
    {
 public ActionResult act(int movieid)
    {
    return Content("movieid = " + movieid);
    }
}
```

и ссылаюсь на http://localhost:49721/Movie/act/1 выдается ошибка. В интернете нашел такую информацию. "В маршуритазоторе аргумент не movieid а id, из за этого аргумент должен быть id". Но не могу понять, если мы передаем число, то тогда какая разница как называется аргумент в action ? Мы же все равно передаем маршрутизатору целое число

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда приходит запрос на URL вида "Movie/act/1", ASP.NET вытаскивает из него три коллекции именованных параметров:

1. GET-параметры: их в этом запросе нет, пустая коллекция;
2. POST-параметры: их в этом запросе тоже нет, снова пустая коллекция;
3. Параметры маршрута (Route Parameters) - вот они-то как раз нашлись. Если у вас уставлена настройка маршрутизации по умолчанию, то эти параметры будут такими:

   - controller = "Movie"
   - action = "act"
   - id = "1"

Первые два параметра используются чтобы найти нужный метод для вызова. Дальше наступает фаза привязки параметров метода. И тут ASP.NET по умолчанию использует **имена параметров**!

Ваш параметр имеет имя `movieid` - и для него значений в коллекции входных параметров не нашлось.

Способы исправления:

1. исправить имя параметра метода:

   ```
   public ActionResult act(int id)
   ```
2. добавить отдельный маршрут для вашего действия:

   ```
   routes.MapRoute("MovieAct", "Movie/act/{movieid}", new { controller = "Movie", action = "act" });
   ```
3. сделать то же самое - но через атрибут:

   ```
   routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

   // ...

   [Route("Movie/act/{movieid}")]
   public ActionResult act(int movieid)
   ```
4. поменять привязку (работает только в ASP.NET Core):

   ```
   public ActionResult act([FromRoute(Name = "id")]int movieid)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

В Вашем Global.asax.cs есть такой код:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
      "Default", // Route name
      "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
      new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
  );
```

При отсутствии других зарегистрированных маршрутов параметр, идущий через слэш после названия экшн метода, называется `id`.

Вы можете написать свой `ModelBinder` для этого метода и называть параметр, как Вам нравится.

Comment: Я знаю это, но все равно же мы передаем туда готовое число. Например 3. Какая разница как эта переменная называется если мы передаем готовое число ?

Comment: @ShamilQurbanli Что в Вашем понимании "готовое число", и чем оно отличается от "неготового"?

Comment: нуу, если мы написали void func(int id) а потом вызываем функцию вот так int movieid = 3; funk(movieid) значит передаем число. Компилятор ошибку не выдает. Соответсвенно, когда создаем public ActionResult foo(int movieid) и пишем http://localhost:49721/Movie/act/3 значит у нас id=3 и в итогу получается movieid=3. Разве не так ? Мы передаем значение 3, какая разница как переменная ?

Comment: @ShamilQurbanli Да, все не так. Привязка значений из URL и других элементов запроса происходит по именам параметров. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding